Python Solana bot transaction issues
I’m attempting to create a solana bot that has limit order to buy $MAGA using raydium. However everytime i run the code, the transaction does not go through.
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
# Returns the swap_transaction to be manipulated in sendTransaction()
async def create_transaction(quote: dict, input_token_mint, output_token_mint) -> dict:
    log_transaction.info(f"""Soltrade is creating transaction for the following quote: 
{quote}""")

    if 'error' in quote:
        log_transaction.error(f"Error in quote: {quote['error']}")
        raise Exception(f"Error in quote: {quote['error']}")

    pool_id = get_pool_id(input_token_mint)
    #pool_id = "9XsGAA3xHC6gqRgThRrcaUPU6jzerZacWgfyMb17579t"

    # Parameters used for the Raydium POST request
    parameters = {
        "quoteResponse": quote,
        "userPublicKey": str(configs['public_address']),
        "wrapUnwrapSOL": True,
        "computeUnitPriceMicroLamports": 20 * 3_000_000  # fee of roughly $.4  :shrug:
    }
    #9XsGAA3xHC6gqRgThRrcaUPU6jzerZacWgfyMb17579t
    # Returns the JSON parsed response of Jupiter
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.post(f"https://api.raydium.io/v2/swap?poolId={pool_id}", json=parameters)
        exchange_data = response.json()

        pprint(f"TRANSACTION CREATE:\n{exchange_data}")
        return exchange_data


async def perform_swap(sent_amount: float, price_limit, sent_token_mint: str, mode : str):
    global position
    log_general.info("Soltrade is taking a limit position.")

    #TODO: fetch the current price and create a limit order
    current_price = get_price(sent_token_mint)

    base_token = await get_token_decimals(sent_token_mint)
    quote = trans = opts = txid = tx_error = None
    is_tx_successful = False

    for i in range(0,3):
        if not is_tx_successful:
            try:
                if (mode == "buy") or (mode == "sell"):
                    quote = await create_exchange(sent_amount, sent_token_mint, mode)
                    trans = await create_transaction(quote, sent_token_mint, SOL_MINT_ADDRESS)
                    print(f"TRANS:\n{trans}")
                    opts = TxOpts(skip_preflight=False, preflight_commitment="confirmed", last_valid_block_height=find_last_valid_block_height())
                    txid = send_transaction(trans["swapTransaction"], opts)

                    for i in range(3):
                        await asyncio.sleep(35)
                        tx_error = find_transaction_error(txid)
                        if not tx_error:
                            is_tx_successful = True
                            break
                else:
                    log_general.info(f"Price hasn't reached {price_limit}. Waiting for the next opportunity.")
                    await asyncio.sleep(60)
                    continue
                    #current_price = get_price(sent_token_mint)

            except Exception as e:
                if RPCException:
                    print(traceback.format_exc())
                    log_general.warning(f"Soltrade failed to complete transaction {i}. Retrying.")
                    continue
                else:
                    raise
            for i in range(0, 3):
                try:
                    await asyncio.sleep(35)
                    tx_error = find_transaction_error(txid)
                    if not tx_error:
                        is_tx_successful = True
                        break
                except TypeError as e:
                    print(traceback.format_exc())
                    log_general.warning("Soltrade failed to verify the existence of the transaction. Retrying.")
                    continue
        else:
            break

<!-- end snippet -->
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
2024-05-27 14:19:22       Soltrade has detected a buy signal.
2024-05-27 14:19:22       Soltrade is taking a limit position.
Response: SOL
2024-05-27 14:19:22       Soltrade is creating exchange for 12.103126943600001 dollars in ('', '')
Pool ID: 8sLbNZoA1cfnvMJLPfp98ZLAnFSYCFApfJKMbiXNLwxj
('EXCHANGE CREATED:\n'
 "{'id': '03c2fd251bb64b3a85a3207deae7b010', 'success': False}")
2024-05-27 14:19:23       Soltrade is creating transaction for the following quote: 
{'id': '03c2fd251bb64b3a85a3207deae7b010', 'success': False}
('TRANSACTION CREATE:\n'
 "{'id': '64218b3c90b943d0a1069e43248f406f', 'success': False}")
TRANS:
{'id': '64218b3c90b943d0a1069e43248f406f', 'success': False}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dekahalane/soltrade-1/soltrade/transactions.py", line 204, in perform_swap
    txid = send_transaction(trans["swapTransaction"], opts)
KeyError: 'swapTransaction'

2024-05-27 14:19:24       Soltrade failed to complete transaction 0. Retrying.

<!-- end snippet -->
I’ve tried debugging, increasing the slippage and the fees. I've researched any Solana python documentation and i couldn't find any. I think the problem could be wrong links.

I happened to fix this by switching to Jupiter api, and using these links :
This in create_exchange()_
https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/quote?inputMint={input_token_mint}&outputMint={output_token_mint}&amount={int(amount_in)}&slippageBps={config().slippage}

This in create_transaction():
 https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap


It looks like you may have issue with "swapTransaction" ... I would suggest you to add error handling (perform_swap function  swap_transaction function) and  to check the response for success and provide meaningful logs or retries if the swap operation fails.
